# Is it possible to set widget options dynamically in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

As a minimal working example,

```
# An app with a datatable whose pagination option we can toggle with a button
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("button", label = "Toggle paginate"),
        dataTableOutput("table")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$table <- renderDataTable(
            data.frame(x = 1:100, y = input$button),   # Some dummy data
            options = list(
                bPaginate = as.logical(input$button %% 2)
            )
        )
    }
))
```

The corresponding browser output:

[image]

I should be able to dynamically switch the option `bPaginate` on and off just by clicking the "Toggle paginate" button.

However, this does not work - the table is never paginated. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the data table widget. Neither `renderDataTable` nor `DT::renderDataTable` appear to recognize and re-render output when options are given as a simple list.

Yihui's answer works for the base Shiny `renderDataTable`, but I would never guess this as a solution and I can't see why a function would work and a plain list wouldn't. I assume it is some internal implementation issue with the underlying Javascript, but this seems like an implementation detail that should not leak out into the R api.

I can't, however, make Yihui's answer work for the `DT` version of the DataTable package. Perhaps this is just my error, but I eventually figured another way to get user input to affect table options without using a function for options. Doing so requires one extra (reactive) variable layer and uses the `datatable()` function. (Note that the latest DataTable version this is all based on uses different option names, and I'm using a slightly different ui than the question above. None of that should change the basic problem or its solution.)

```r
# An app with a datatable whose pagination option we can toggle with a button
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
   ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput("paging", "Paginate table")
         ),
         mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("table")
         )
      )
   ),
   server = function(input, output) {
      # Create a new table when input$paging changes
      makeTable <- reactive({
         DT::datatable(
            { data.frame(x= 1:100, y = input$paging)},   # Some dummy data
            options= list(
               paging = input$paging
            )
         )
      })
      # Render the datatable returned by the reactive function
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( makeTable() )
   }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to return the DataTable options, e.g.

```
options = function() {
  list(
    bPaginate = as.logical(input$button %% 2)
  )
}
```

Note this requires shiny >= 0.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stuart. Your example works right off the bat.

Here is your code for a `flexdashboard`:

````
---
title: "Datatable Pagination"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
# shiny inputs defined here
checkboxInput("paging", "Paginate table")
```


## Column

### Data Table

```{r}

makeTable <- reactive({
    DT::datatable(
        { data.frame(x= 1:100, y = input$paging)},   # Some dummy data
        options= list(
            paging = input$paging
        )
    )
})
# Render the datatable returned by the reactive function
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( makeTable() )

DT::dataTableOutput("table")

```
````